# Como usar o floodfill do PIL em python?

Tags: python, imagem

Eu estou tentando colorir uma barra usando o pacote PIL do python. Essa é a barra original:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de colorir a parte interna inteira, com apenas uma cor. Eu tentei usar o `floodfill` para isso:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

im = Image.open('progress.jpeg')
width, height = im.size
center = (int(0.5*width), int(0.33* height))
yellow = (255, 255, 0, 255)
ImageDraw.floodfill(im, xy=center, value=yellow)
im.save('result.png')
```

E obtive o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inicialmente, eu imaginei que o `floodfill` colorisse todos os pixels que estão entre o width e a height específicadas no argumento `xy`. Como peguei 1/3 da altura e metade do cumprimento, ele pintou de amarelo a área interna da esquerda para a direita, a partir da metade. No entanto, se uso 100% da width, o programa não colore nada. Então, obviamente, minha interpretação está errada.

Como o floodfill funciona? Como posso colorir a barra interna completamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembra da função do "baldinho" do Paint? O `floodfill` funciona de forma análoga: você passa uma cor e um ponto XY, e o PIL tenta "preencher" a região ao redor do ponto XY com a cor desejada.

É claro que o ponto de corte para definir a região limite do preenchimento vai depender da sua aplicação - talvez você queira que o preenchimento pegue regiões de cores *parecidas, mas não idênticas* à cor da região em que você adicionou a cor. Você pode controlar isso com o argumento `thresh`.

Para colorir a barra inteira no seu caso, acredito que o mais simples seja utilizar o `floodfill` duas vezes - passando uma posição XY dentro da região verde, e uma posição XY dentro da região preta. Se todos os pixels de cada região tiverem a mesma intensidade, você nem precisa se preocupar com o argumento `thresh`.

#### Edit

Testei a sua imagem e a cor ao longo da barra realmente não é homogênea - mas se utilizarmos um `thresh` suficientemente alto, conseguimos preencher a barra totalmente. Abaixo o exemplo de código que faz o que você quer:

```
im = Image.open('progress.jpeg')
width, height = im.size
green_region = (int(0.4*width), int(0.33*height))
black_region = (int(0.6*width), int(0.33* height))
yellow = (255, 255, 0, 255)
for region in (green_region, black_region):
    ImageDraw.floodfill(im, xy=region, value=yellow, thresh=150)
im.save('result.png')
```

Output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A documentação do `floodfill` está [aqui](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.floodfill).

#### Exemplos:

- Imagem de entrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Executando seu código na imagem (usa o argumento padrão `thresh=0` - note o pixel amarelo sozinho no chapéu):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Adicionando o argumento `thresh=30`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Adicionando o argumento `thresh=100`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]